# Liferay cannot get user by screenname

Tags: liferay, autologin, opensso, openam

I'm writing an autologin hook for liferay, which tries to get the user by screenname. I'm using following code to get the user, which mainly is a variation of [OpenSSOAutoLogin](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/src-html/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/OpenSSOAutoLogin.html):

`User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(companyId, screenName);`

This works in most of cases, except when screenname which is recorded in liferay is uppercase. For instance, I cannot get user if the screenname stored liferay is 'TEST'. The stack trace shows following:

```
com.liferay.portal.NoSuchUserException: No User exists with the key {companyId=1, screenName=test}
    at com.liferay.portal.service.persistence.UserPersistenceImpl.findByC_SN(UserPersistenceImpl.java:2789)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.UserLocalServiceImpl.getUserByScreenName(UserLocalServiceImpl.java:2590)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
    at $Proxy103.getUserByScreenName(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(UserLocalServiceUtil.java:1625)
    at me.and.my.business.MyAutoLogin.login(MyAutoLogin.java:175)
```

The trace clearly says that "No user exists with the key screenName=test". Here 'test' is written in lowercase, but getUserByScreenName() method was called with uppercase screenname.

After some research, I could find that a lowercase conversion is performed in [liferay UserLocalServiceImpl](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/src-html/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/UserLocalServiceImpl.html#line.5175). I guess it is the reason that make the search fail, but I'm not really sure.

Can anyone confirm that ? Should the liferay screen names always be un lowercase ?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: I think the `companyId` passed is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

Upon saving a new user, Liferay always transforms the screen name to lower case. As you said, the method is found in UserLocalServiceImpl.java

```
protected String getScreenName(String screenName) {
    return StringUtil.lowerCase(StringUtil.trim(screenName));
}
```

So it does not matter if you pass in the screen name with upper case when creating / updating a user, Liferay will always transform it.